# Laravel 7: Automatically add values to a column on first day of every month

Tags: laravel, cron, laravel-7, cron-task, laravel-scheduler

I want to add value to specific column for all rows in a table every month.

Users Table:

| id | leave_alloc | leave_earn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 0 |
| 2 | 20 | 1.5 |
| 3 | 20 | -3 |
| 4 | 20 | 4 |

Controller:

```
public function earned_leave(){
  $user = User::where('leave_alloc', '!=', null)->get();
  foreach($user as $row){
    $leave_alloc = $row->leave_alloc;
    $earned_leave = $leave_alloc / 12;
    $row->leave_earn += $earned_leave;
    $row->save();
  }
}
```

Here `$earned_leave` will be the result of `$leave_alloc` divided by `12`. So, on the first day of every month, I want to add the earned leave amount to the `leave_earn` column of all users. This column can hold a negative value and decimal value.

How can I make this automation?

Comment: you can create a schedule  with option `monthly()` . document : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#schedule-frequency-options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel support [task scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling#defining-schedules). For your task you may use `->monthlyOn(4, '15:00');`

In most simple realization it looks like

```php
$schedule->call(function () {
  $user = User::where('leave_alloc', '!=', null)->get();
  foreach($user as $row){
    $earned_leave = $row->leave_alloc / 12;
    $row->leave_earn += $earned_leave;
    $row->save();
  }
})->monthlyOn(1, '12:00');
```

Don't forget to add [Cron entry](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling#introduction)

Comment: Thanks, I'm checking. Is my calculation part correct?

Comment: Will it run on the local server?

Comment: @ShanMdShazarulHaque171-15- yes it is. You may write a console command and call it manually.